# base64 decoder (io.Reader implementation) misbehaviour

Tags: file, go, io, reader

I have tried, within a for loop, to re-declare/assign a base64 decoder and used the os.Seek function to go back to the beginning of the file at the end of the loop before this, in order for the called function (in this test case PrintBytes) to be able to process the file from beginning to end time and time again throughout the for loop.

Here is my (I'm sure terribly un-idiomatic) code, which fails to read the 2nd byte into the []byte of length 2 and capacity 2 during the second iteration of the main for loop in main():

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/base64"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

var (
    remote_file string = "http://cryptopals.com/static/challenge-data/6.txt"
    local_file  string = "secrets_01_06.txt"
)

func main() {
    f, err := os.Open(local_file)
    if err != nil {
        DownloadFile(local_file, remote_file)
        f, err = os.Open(local_file)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }
    defer f.Close()

    for blocksize := 1; blocksize <= 5; blocksize++ {
        decoder := base64.NewDecoder(base64.StdEncoding, f)
        PrintBytes(decoder, blocksize)
        _, err := f.Seek(0, 0)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }
}

func PrintBytes(reader io.Reader, blocksize int) {
    block := make([]byte, blocksize)
    for {
        n, err := reader.Read(block)
        if err != nil && err != io.EOF {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        if n != blocksize {
            log.Printf("n=%d\tblocksize=%d\tbreaking...", n, blocksize)
            break
        }
        log.Printf("%x\tblocksize=%d", block, blocksize)
    }
}

func DownloadFile(local string, url string) {
    f, err := os.Create(local)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()

    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    _, err = io.Copy(f, resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

The output from this code can be viewed here https://gist.github.com/tomatopeel/b8e2f04179c7613e2a8c8973a72ec085

It is this behaviour that I don't understand:
https://gist.github.com/tomatopeel/b8e2f04179c7613e2a8c8973a72ec085#file-bad_reader_log-L5758

I was expecting it to simply read the file 2 bytes at a time into the 2-byte slice, from beginning to end. For what reason does it only read 1 byte here?

Comment: I don't think the base64 decoder is stateless, so `Seek`ing the underlying reader between reads from the base64 reader may have unpredictable results.

Comment: the intent of this code is extremely unclear.  i had to go back to the original challenge to understand what is going on with iterating over block size (which looks strange because it's not using an accumulated n to ensure that it eventually reads blocksize bytes).  Just `asBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(base64.NewDecoder(base64.StdEncoding, f))`, and proceed to work on the data asBytes.  (ie: the distance calculations between block lengths, etc.)

Comment: @Rob The only intent of the code here was as a demo for the question. It's a modified excerpt from some obviously buggy code for the given challenge. I just continued to use the file from the challenge, I suppose out of laziness. I will look into using an accumulated n though, thank you, I'm new to golang.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not the problem of `encoding/base64`. When using [`io.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader), it's not guaranteed that number of bytes read exactly equal to the buffer size (i.e. `blocksize` in your example code). The documentation states:

> Read reads up to len(p) bytes into p. It returns the number of bytes read (0 <= n <= len(p)) and any error encountered. Even if Read returns n < len(p), it may use all of p as scratch space during the call. If some data is available but not len(p) bytes, Read conventionally returns what is available instead of waiting for more.

In your example, change `PrintBytes` to

```
func PrintBytes(reader io.Reader, blocksize int) {
    block := make([]byte, blocksize)
    for {
        n, err := reader.Read(block)
        //Process the data if n > 0, even when err != nil
        if n > 0 {
            log.Printf("%x\tblocksize=%d", block[:n], blocksize)
        }

        //Check for error
        if err != nil {
            if err != io.EOF {
                log.Fatal(err)
            } else if err == io.EOF {
                break
            }
        } else if n == 0 {
            //Considered as nothing happened
            log.Printf("WARNING: read return 0,nil")
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**

Correct usage of `io.Reader`, modify code to always process the data if `n > 0` even when error occurs.